# jQuery validation localization not working

Tags: jquery

Hope my question does not appear to be too stupid.

I've been working on this issue for days.

Here's my question :
how can I get the jQuery plug-in to work with the localization files ? My goal is to be able to display error messages in English or in French in my contact form. If the visitor is looking at my page in French I would like him to see validation messages in the contact form in the same language.

Even if I've tried other solutions none worked.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><?php echo $lang['PAGE_TITLE_CONTACT']; ?></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400italic|Fjalla+One|Signika:700|Lobster|Cuprum:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            </head>
        <body>

            <?php
        include 'includes/navigation_menu.php';
     ?>

            <div id="languages">
            <a href="contact.php?lang=en"><img src="images/pays/eng.png" /></a>
            <a href="contact.php?lang=fr"><img src="images/pays/fr.png" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="mainDiv">
                <div id="texteContact">
                    <p class="infosContact"><?php echo $lang['TEXT_ONE_FORM']; ?><br />
                    <?php echo $lang['TEXT_TWO_FORM']; ?></p>   

                        <?php echo $lang['TEXT_FIVE_FORM']; ?> <br />
                        <?php echo $lang['TEXT_SIX_FORM']; ?>   
                    </p>                
                    <div id="btnLinkedIn">
                    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang:en_US</script>
                    <script type="IN/Share"></script>
                    </div>
                    <p class="infosContact">Mon code GitHub :</p>               
                </div>
                <form id="formulaire" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" >
                    <label><?php echo $lang['INPUT_NAME']; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['PLACEHOLDER_NAME']; ?>" />
                    <label><?php echo $lang['INPUT_EMAIL']; ?></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['PLACEHOLDER_EMAIL']; ?>" />
                    <label><?php echo $lang['INPUT_OBJECT']; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="object" name="object" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['PLACEHOLDER_OBJECT']; ?>" />
                    <label><?php echo $lang['INPUT_MESSAGE']; ?></label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['PLACEHOLDER_MESSAGE']; ?>" ></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['INPUT_SEND']; ?>" id="sendBtn" name="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>      
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>             
            <!-- jQuery Validation Plugin-->        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="localization/messages_fr.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If I leave only this line all messages will obviously be displayed in English :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

However if I add this line for French messages all the error messages will be in French (which was dowloaded from https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization). Why ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="localization/messages_fr.js"></script>
```

I've read that if we wanted to add other languages we only needed to add the corresponding file in localization folder.

Finally here's the French portion from localization file :

```
    /*
 * Translated default messages for the jQuery validation plugin.
 * Locale: FR (French; français)
 */
$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "Ce champ est obligatoire.",
    remote: "Veuillez corriger ce champ.",
    email: "Veuillez fournir une adresse électronique valide.",
    url: "Veuillez fournir une adresse URL valide.",
    date: "Veuillez fournir une date valide.",
    dateISO: "Veuillez fournir une date valide (ISO).",
    number: "Veuillez fournir un numéro valide.",
    digits: "Veuillez fournir seulement des chiffres.",
    creditcard: "Veuillez fournir un numéro de carte de crédit valide.",
    equalTo: "Veuillez fournir encore la même valeur.",
    extension: "Veuillez fournir une valeur avec une extension valide.",
    maxlength: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir au plus {0} caractères." ),
    minlength: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir au moins {0} caractères." ),
    rangelength: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir une valeur qui contient entre {0} et {1} caractères." ),
    range: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir une valeur entre {0} et {1}." ),
    max: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir une valeur inférieure ou égale à {0}." ),
    min: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir une valeur supérieure ou égale à {0}." ),
    maxWords: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir au plus {0} mots." ),
    minWords: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir au moins {0} mots." ),
    rangeWords: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir entre {0} et {1} mots." ),
    letterswithbasicpunc: "Veuillez fournir seulement des lettres et des signes de ponctuation.",
    alphanumeric: "Veuillez fournir seulement des lettres, nombres, espaces et soulignages.",
    lettersonly: "Veuillez fournir seulement des lettres.",
    nowhitespace: "Veuillez ne pas inscrire d'espaces blancs.",
    ziprange: "Veuillez fournir un code postal entre 902xx-xxxx et 905-xx-xxxx.",
    integer: "Veuillez fournir un nombre non décimal qui est positif ou négatif.",
    vinUS: "Veuillez fournir un numéro d'identification du véhicule (VIN).",
    dateITA: "Veuillez fournir une date valide.",
    time: "Veuillez fournir une heure valide entre 00:00 et 23:59.",
    phoneUS: "Veuillez fournir un numéro de téléphone valide.",
    phoneUK: "Veuillez fournir un numéro de téléphone valide.",
    mobileUK: "Veuillez fournir un numéro de téléphone mobile valide.",
    strippedminlength: $.validator.format( "Veuillez fournir au moins {0} caractères." ),
    email2: "Veuillez fournir une adresse électronique valide.",
    url2: "Veuillez fournir une adresse URL valide.",
    creditcardtypes: "Veuillez fournir un numéro de carte de crédit valide.",
    ipv4: "Veuillez fournir une adresse IP v4 valide.",
    ipv6: "Veuillez fournir une adresse IP v6 valide.",
    require_from_group: "Veuillez fournir au moins {0} de ces champs.",
    nifES: "Veuillez fournir un numéro NIF valide.",
    nieES: "Veuillez fournir un numéro NIE valide.",
    cifES: "Veuillez fournir un numéro CIF valide.",
    postalCodeCA: "Veuillez fournir un code postal valide."
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could load localization only if needed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['lang'] ) && 'fr' === $_GET['lang'] ) : ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="localization/messages_fr.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Nicola ! Your solution seems to be working.